# How to display content in php that is returned by ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the webpage with the following AJAX script:

```
<script>
    $("#sendbtn").click(function() {
        var text = $("#textarea").val();
        var mail = $("#email").val();
        var id= 1; 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'savedatanow.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                text: text,
                mail: mail,
                id: id
            },
            success: function(response)
            {

                $('#email').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#textarea').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#sendbtn').prop('disabled', true);
                alert("Thanks!");

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

and in `savedatanow.php` I have the part of the code that parse the data and adds it into the database. At the end of the php file I have the command `echo "added";`, but that obvioulsy doesn't show up. Is there any way of displaying the returned data on my webpage (besides using the alert() in javascript)? I would like maybe to create some div on my webpage that will be filled with returned content, but then - what should I use on php site besides `echo "";`? and how should I modify my javascript?

Comment: The response in success callback is the stuff you echo in php. You can use it to create new div or find existing one and change the text inside.

Comment: in the success function, use javascript to insert the returned data into a DOM element